# Adding URL parameters to form action in flask

Tags: python, forms, flask

Is there a way to pass an additional list of parameters outside of a form when the form is submit?

I know I can create a new hidden input field in the form for each parameter I want to pass through the form, but is there another way? I tried to add parameters directly to the form action but that doesn't work. The code in its entirety can be found here:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  print request.args
  return "<form action='/?foo=bar'><input name='variable' type='text' /></form>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
  app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=port)
```

Clarifying question based on feedback from comments:

Using this code, when I type "123" into the textbox and hit enter, I see that the url is `http://my-workspace.c9users.io/?variable=123`.

What I want is `http://my-workspace.c9users.io/?foo=bar&variable=12‌​3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should show what you input and what you want output.

In your code, the `index()` function default accept the `GET` method, so if you want to post data from form add the `methods` to the `@app.route()`.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

and, the form also should add post method.

```
<form method='post', action='/'></form>
```